# Проприетарный драйвер nvidia в fedora

Tags: linux, fedora, nvidia, видеодрайвера

Перешел с windows на fedora (gnome wayland) на домашнем пк и столкнулся со следующей проблемой.

Устанавливал дистрибутив через basic graphics mode, затем подключил репозиторий nvidia и установил их проприетарный драйвер. Всё было хорошо, пока не попробовал запустить майнер. Увидел что хешрейт вдвое меньше чем был на винде, при этом другие приложения, задействующие графику, начинают подтормаживать. На винде же с этим было всё гладко.

Также возникли вопросы с применением разгона. Что мне стоит проверить в первую очередь? Возможно дело в том, что драйвер nvidia версии 515.65. На винде же стояла версия 512 вроде. В таком случае я не знаю как правильно откатить драйвер до 512, не сломав то, что уже работает.

карта rtx 3060 (lhr v2)

Comment: Объясни свой выбор в пользу Федоры. Чем не подошел убунту? Я просто через приложение драйверы нужное все поставил и радуюсь. Что за видеокарта? Может, буде оптимальнее и вовсе на 470-ю версию дров перейти? А те дрова, что у тебя, они и вовсе в бете, сделанные опенсорсными по требованию хак-группировки LAPSUS$, а Red Hat очень против проприетарности в Федоре. А так тебе еще придется познать подключение других репо, и, возможно, и вовсе на пару минут остаться с одним терминалом.

Comment: Спасибо, что добавил модель карты. Как я и думал, нужна более старая версия дров. Попробуй 490xx

Comment: Удаление сделать очень просто - как программу через dnf удаляй, и переходи на иксы (опционально, старые дрова не очень с вейландом дружат)

Comment: sudo dnf remove nvidia* libnvidia*